# Cannot install lparallel alongside CL21 (?) Failing with CL21.CORE.FUNCTION

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I have a weird mix of errors.

I was using CL21, I was in my package, and I wanted to install lparallel. Not possible:

```
(ql:quickload :lparallel)
To load "lparallel":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    lparallel
; Loading "lparallel"
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   DYNAMIC-EXTENT on a weird thing: (CL21.CORE.FUNCTION:FUNCTION #:BODY-FN1)
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
; Evaluation aborted on #<UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR {1008956C13}>.
```

I can reproduce it in a new session but it's a bit weird: if I `quickload` lparallel in `cl-user`, it complains on not finding the symbol `CL21.CORE.FUNCTION`, even if I didn't do nothing with CL21 yet:

```
The name "CL21.CORE.FUNCTION" does not designate any package.
```

So I ql:quickload CL21 and then on retrying to load lparallel. I get the first error.

But, I tried in Portacle for a fresh image and… I couldn't reproduce this.

Any idea ? Is that an issue with `cl21`, `lparallel`, `quicklisp` or `asdf`??

Comment: Looks like cl21 messes the standard readtable by replacing `#'` with its own version that isn't compatible with lparallel. Try `(ql:quickload :lparallel :force t)` in a fresh image to get rid of the files compiled with cl21 loaded.

Comment: No luck with this command. Indeed, cl21 replaces `#'`.

Comment: I also filled an issue: https://github.com/cl21/cl21/issues/99 and a working suggestion is to use `(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lparallel :force t)` (or to delete the .fasd files). You were close !

Comment: Oh right, `ql:quickload` apparently doesn't pass `:force t` to asdf as I thought.

Comment: If you want to explain the pb and the solution in an answer I will definitely accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cl21` seems to replace the standard reader macro `#'` with its own version that isn't compatible with `lparallel`. When you tried to load `lparallel` in a fresh image, ASDF will load it from the `.fasl`-files that were compiled with `cl21` loaded, so you must either delete those files or force recompilation with

```
(asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op :lparallel :force t)
```

Loading `cl21` after `lparallel` is compiled with the standard language shouldn't cause the same problem.

Comment: Very clear thank you ! (except "When tried you load " => "when you tried to load" ?)